# Sendmail doesn't work on PHP

Tags: php, centos, sendmail

I have a big problem setting up sendmail on a CentOs/nginx server.
If I use the command line sendmail does work, but if I use phpmailer it simply says "could not istantiate mail function".

I've even tried with traditional one-line command:

```
   mail('mail@mail.com', 'test', 'you done that','From: postmaster@mydomain.com');
```

but it doesn't return error or anything.

Phpinfo() confirms that the following values are correctly set:

```
sendmail_from   postmaster@mydomain.com
sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

Where's the problem? Thanks a lot

Comment: It must return an error - have you checked the error logs?

Comment: Please attempt your own debugging. Does sendmail work in cli ?

Comment: @LuckyBurger yes it does

Comment: Your header isn't properly set. They need to be terminated with "\r\n"

Comment: if it isn't showing anything I think it works. I know that PhpMailer sometimes throw this error when charset wasn't set correctly. maybe that's the reason

Comment: I've just discovered a little php.ini that disabled mail function. I'm sorry for the dumb question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Please try this example.